# Showing that a line with two origins is locally hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

$ \mathbb{X}=\left(\left\{ 1\right\} \times\mathbb{R}\right)\cup\left(\mathbb{R}\times\left\{ 2\right\} \right)$ and consider $\mathbb{X}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ Define an equivalence relation by $\left(x,1\right)\sim\left(x,2\right)\iff x\neq0$.
Show that the quotient space $\mathbb{X}/_{\sim}$ determined by this equivalence relation is locally Hausdorff.

The definition of locally Hausdorff is as follows: for all $x\in \mathbb{X}/_{\sim}$ exists $U\subseteq \mathbb{X}/_{\sim}$ open neighborhood of $x$ such that $U$ with the subspace topology is Hausdorff.

I've been able to show that the quotient space $\mathbb{X}/_{\sim}$ is not Hausdorff, I'm having trouble constructing open neighborhood $U$ of $\left(1,0\right)$ or $\left(0,2\right)$ that satisfies that the subspace if Hausdorff

Comment: Hint : show that the two inclusions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$ are both open embeddings.